# How to open route with another protocol?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have ember application which opens with http but I have button for videochat but WebRTC works only on page with https. So I need open route in new window and with https protocol. Can I do it with `link-to`?
My link:

`{{#link-to "videochat" model.id class="call-button" target="_blank"}}Call{{/link-to}}`

Now I'm doing with `window.open` in controller action, but some browsers block opened window.

Comment: Why not use HTTPS everywhere in your application?

Comment: It's the easiest solution. I don't see how you would even be in the situation where only a specific URL in your domain would use HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by re-binding the rendered anchor's `href` attribute to a new computed property `hrefWithProtocol`.
Add the following initializer:

```js
// app/initializers/customize-link-to.js

import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  LinkComponent,
  computed
} = Ember

export function initialize() {

  LinkComponent.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['hrefWithProtocol:href'],
    hrefWithProtocol: computed('href', 'protocol', function() {
      let {
        href,
        protocol
      } = this.getProperties('href', 'protocol');

      if (protocol) {
        href = protocol + '://' + window.location.host + href;
      }

      return href;
    })
  })
}

export default {
  name: 'customize-link-to',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

In your template add the new `protocol` attr:

```html
{{#link-to "videochat" model.id
  classNames="call-button"
  target="_blank"
  protocol='https'}}
  Call
{{/link-to}}
```